# Different intercept’s meaning?

Tags: r, lm

Given that I have three categorical variables (x1,x2,x3) with two levels each.

```
x1 <- as.factor(c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)))
x2 <- sample(x1)
x3 <- sample(x1)
y <- rnorm (10, 3,3)
res1 <- lm ( y~ x1+x2+x3)
summary(res1)
```

Then the `lm` function it returns the following

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)    3.658      1.869   1.957   0.0981 .
x12            3.071      2.786   1.102   0.3127  
x22            1.275      2.275   0.560   0.5956  
x32           -2.818      2.786  -1.011   0.3510
```

so my model looks like y=b0+b1*x1+b2*x2+b3*x3

On the other hand when I am running this analysis (again three categorical variables in two levels each)

```
X <- melt(cbind(x1,x2,x3))[,-1]
Y <- rnorm (30, 3,3)
res2 <- lm ( Y~X[,2])
summary(res2)
```

the results are:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   3.0171     1.7845   1.691    0.102
X[, 2]       -0.2308     1.1286  -0.204    0.839
```

Here is the so called "effects model" where the intercept is actually the overall effect and the X[, 2] is the effect of the variable.

Indeed the two examples are different, but I don’t understand why lm function gives different format of model hence **different meaning of intercept** ?

Comment: This seems more like a question of statistical modelling. You should probably ask this on [crossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), as SO is for focused questions on programming problems. However, you might do a search on the site before posting. This is a common question.

Comment: I think the issue arises from different datatypes, so the question may be appropriate on SO after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference arises because the second model uses another (wrong) datatype.

In your first model you have 3 predictors which are factors with 2 levels each. The datatype `factor` tells R that these are categorical variables and so R assumes that you are interested in the different means for the different levels.

In your second model you have only one predictor, `X[, 2]`, which is a normal vector (of doubles) and no longer a `factor`. R does not know that this predictor has only two levels and assumes it is a continuousvariable. Thus you get a model with intercept and slope.

If you explicitly convert `X[, 2]` to a factor again everything works out:

```
res3 <- lm ( Y~factor(X[, 2]))
summary(res3)


Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       3.1515     0.7403   4.257  0.00021 ***
factor(X[, 2])2  -0.5892     1.0469  -0.563  0.57808
```

Usually this standard behaviour is correct, but anyway you can tell R exactly how it should code your variables by using "contrasts". [This article](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/65059_586f394d8eb84f84b1baaf56ffb6b47f.html) provides a good overview if you are interested.

Comment: contrast() was what I was looking